# SwiftUI container relative shape usage

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
struct testwidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ZStack {
                ContainerRelativeShape()
                    .fill(.yellow)
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer(minLength: 100)
                        ContainerRelativeShape()
                            .fill(.blue)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Spacer(minLength: 100)
                        ContainerRelativeShape()
                            .fill(.blue)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Spacer(minLength: 100)
                        ContainerRelativeShape()
                            .fill(.blue)
                    }
                }
            }
            ZStack {
                ContainerRelativeShape()
                    .fill(.yellow)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

The second blue view has no corner radius:

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way to make the second blue view has the same corner radius with the other two by using the container relative shape? Or there is some other ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: I found that it works if any of the sides of the middle blue rectangle are in contact with an outside edge of the widget. So it works if the rectangles are left aligned in the first ```ZStack```, or if they use the full width of the ```ZStack```, or if the second ```ZStack``` is not there, or if the second ```ZStack```is on the left side. But as it stands, the middle blue rectangle has no contact with any of the edges of the widget. I couldn't find any trick using overlays or offset either, so it seems to be using a low-level native check that looks for edge contact.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly define the relative shape on the outer `HStack` and on the inner `VStack` with `.containerShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: X.X))`

Comment: What you suggest is what's missing in the question's code to make it look like in the screenshot. But it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @soundflix you're right, I corrected my answer to say it needs applied on the inner VStack too. This seems like a SwiftUI bug imo

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to say it's a widget's code. So I can't get the matched corner radius if I set the containerShape to a hard coded RoundedRectangle, because I can't get the corner radius of the widget dynamically.